# ORA-27102: out of memory

Tags: oracle, oracle-12c, memory

We're facing an Out Memory Problem with an Oracle database SE 12c Release 1 (deployed as a Docker container) ...

The only information that I have is this one:

```
Caused by: java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: ORA-01034: ORACLE not available
ORA-27102: out of memory
Linux-x86_64 Error: 12: Cannot allocate memory Additional information: 2673 
Additional information: 360449 Additional information: 1627389952
```

I try to google the `ORA-27102` but the forum discussions are to broad (to implement any solution will be like shotting in the dark) ... I don't know how to narrow my problem? Does anyone know what those `additional information` codes  are (I tried to google them without success) ??

Any suggestion will be appreciated!

Comment: The value for memory may be too high, check all your memory related parameters in spfile/ifile, modify them accordingly to your system and you should be able to start Oracle.

Comment: Oracle starts okey, the problem happens when the application is running and interacting with the database...

Answer (score 2):

I'm presuming you don't have metalink as this was the first hit:

**SYMPTOMS**

Instance not reachable and process dying.

Background processes are dying and oracle is unable to spawn new processes. Clients cannot connect and they receive error:

```
java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: ORA-01034: ORACLE not available
ORA-27102: out of memory
Linux-x86_64 Error: 12: Cannot allocate memory
Additional information: 2673
Additional information: 488341508
Additional information: 1744830464
```

When this happens local connections are not possible, but already existing connections continue to work. The problem appears when running backups or complex queries then it disappears.

No specific memory related error is reported on the server log just logs like this one:

```
Errors in file /u01/app/oracle/diag/rdbms/alma/ALMA2/trace/ALMA2_cjq0_6234.trc:
Process J000 died, see its trace file
Thu Apr 06 14:25:40 2017
kkjcre1p: unable to spawn jobq slave process   <=============  important symptom
Thu Apr 06 14:25:40 2017
Errors in file /u01/app/oracle/diag/rdbms/alma/ALMA2/trace/ALMA2_cjq0_6234.trc:
Process PPA2 died, see its trace file
Process J000 died, see its trace file
Thu Apr 06 14:25:42 2017
kkjcre1p: unable to spawn jobq slave process
```

**CAUSE**

This is was investigated in

> Bug 24921392 CJQ FAILED TO SPAWN SLAVE PROCESS KKJCRE1P: UNABLE TO
>   SPAWN JOBQ SLAVE PROCESS

The problem may be seen if MEMORY_TARGET is used and memory or swap space is under pressure.

**SOLUTION**

Apply `patch 24921392` if available

OR

As a workaround, increase memory and/or swap on the affected system to avoid the issue.